# Should I use worker or web dyno in this case on Heroku?

Tags: ruby, performance, heroku

I'm not sure if my application fits for worker or web dyno. Let's say I have a web application which can analyse plain text from user and use analysed keywords to find all the documents in my database which is full-text indexed. Now this process might take sometime because after I get all the documents I have to filter out some of the document that users don't want to see. I also use Levenshtein distance algorithm to calculate the relevance of the returned documents from the keywords as well. So, I cannot calculate this in advance and cache the results.

The process is like a synchronous procedure to me. So, I'm not sure how can I make it faster by queueing the process up in worker dyno? Because users have to wait on the webpage to see the results anyway. And sometime I get H12 Request Timeout.

And I think increasing web dyno wouldn't help in this case because even though it's just one user it's gonna be one process and sometime it's longer than 30s. But I also don't know how to use worker dyno to make the application faster. Any suggestions would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Increasing dynos will not help here. If it's something the user needs to wait on, you're better off with a worker doing the work and asynchronously updating the user when it's complete. You may not make it faster this way (though maybe you can because your work loads less code?), but you wont run into H12's and the user isn't stuck waiting on a page to render, wondering if it's taking a long time, or broken.

Comment: And this is what I'm doing right now. So, when user hits the page, I show the page immediately and use Ajax to fetch the results. So, there's loading icon all the time. But I guess ajax request is also a web process. So, that means when the ajax request is fired. I had to put that into worker and return the results when it's finished?

Comment: You could try firing the job on page load (creates job, picked up by background worker), then using ajax to poll a url that will return data for a key (generated with the firing) *if it has data*. When the worker finishes, it creates a record with that key/data. So the the web process(es) are limited to 1) create job 2) do you have data yet?